# RabbitMQ amqp.node integration with nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rabbitmq, amqp

The official RabbitMQ Javascript tutorials show usage of the [amqp.node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib) client library

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    // Note: on Node 6 Buffer.from(msg) should be used
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Hello World!'));
    console.log(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'");
  });
});
```

However, I find it's hard to reuse this code elsewhere. In particular, I don't know how to exports the channel object since it's in a callback. For example in my NodeJs/Express App:

```
app.post('/posts', (req, res) => {
    -- Create a new Post
    -- Publish a message saying that a new Post has been created
    -- Another 'newsfeed' server consume that message and update the newsfeed table
    // How do I reuse the channel 'ch' object from amqp.node here
});
```

Do you guys have any guidance on this one? Suggestion of other libraries is welcomed (Since I'm starting out, ease of use is what I considered the most important)

Comment: If you need to export the channel object, you can use the `module.exports` in the file where you create the channel. for instance call `module.exports.channel = ch` inside the `conn.createChannel` callback. Then you can access this from a different file where you 'required' the channel creating script like this: `channelCreatingScript.channel`.

Comment: It will start out undefined

Comment: You can put the exports statement outside - and assign it a `null` or a `{}`. The  when you assign a new value via `module.exports.channel` it will update it.

Comment: Anyway to enforce the exports to only happen after the channel has been created?

Comment: In that case you only do in the callback, and then when you use it, just be sure to check against `undefined` TypeErrors. Give it a try and let me know. I have put down a sample code in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

amqp.node is a low-level API set that does minimal translation from AMQP to Node.js. It's basically a driver that should be used from a more friendly API.

If you want a DIY solution, create an API that you can export from your module and manage the connection, channel and other objects from within that API file.

But I don't recommend doing it yourself. It's not easy to get things right.

I would suggest using a library like Rabbot (https://github.com/arobson/rabbot/) to handle this for you.

I've been using Rabbot for quite some time now, and I really like the way it works. It pushes the details of AMQP off to the side and lets me focus on the business value of my applications and the messaging patterns that I need, to build featurs.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, you could use the `module.exports` to expose the newly created channel. Of course this will be overridden each time you create a new channel, unless you want to keep an array of channels or some other data structure.
Assuming this is in a script called `channelCreator.js`:

```
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    //this is where you can export the channel object
    module.exports.channel = ch;  
    //moved the sending-code to some 'external script'
  });
});
```

In the script where you may want to use the "exported" channel:

```
    var channelCreator = require("<path>/channelCreator.js");
    //this is where you can access the channel object:
    if(channelCreator.channel){
      channelCreator.channel.sendToQueue('QueueName', new Buffer('This is Some Message.'));
      console.log(" [x] Sent 'Message'");
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if channelCreator.channel is undefined? I can't just drop my message right? Possible scenario is that I wait for it to be initialized, but I don't really know when it will be

Comment: I really appreciate your help my friend. I truly thank you for spending your time with me :D

Comment: Happy to help. In your case where you want to wait until the channel is created, then I really think you need to use a callback function just as the `amqplib` example shows.

Comment: while this will technically work, it introduces race conditions and large problems to your code. you should never call `module.exports` from inside of a callback.

Comment: I ended up writing my own library that wrap around amqplib: https://github.com/rocketspacer/ezamqplib lol xD